# Wordwrap will issue link src and img src

Tags: php

```
<?=$postcontent = wordwrap($qry_post['content'], 67, "<br />", true);?>
```

if content has a long link in it, or a big code, it will halt it at some part and 
 it, will result in an html entity because of the new line/
 in the src code.

any way to fix this?
thanks!

Comment: wordwrap is best for just words without HTML markup, its better to remove last argument `true` for preventing broking apart longer words... such as src which is URI..

Comment: If you're outputting HTML, why do you need to wordwrap at all, given that browsers will format the text how they please, and ignore your word wrapping anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments for the [manual for `wordwrap()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php#59257) someone posted a code snippet to solve this issue:

```
<?php 
    function textWrap($text) { 
        $new_text = ''; 
        $text_1 = explode('>',$text); 
        $sizeof = sizeof($text_1); 
        for ($i=0; $i<$sizeof; ++$i) { 
            $text_2 = explode('<',$text_1[$i]); 
            if (!empty($text_2[0])) { 
                $new_text .= preg_replace('#([^\n\r .]{25})#i', '\\1  ', $text_2[0]); 
            } 
            if (!empty($text_2[1])) { 
                $new_text .= '<' . $text_2[1] . '>';    
            } 
        } 
        return $new_text; 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: thank you sir.
for security reasons, so one cannot type "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz" and mess up the main template and the content div. am i doing it wrong?